# JQuery : What is the difference between "var test" and "var $test"

Tags: javascript, jquery

what is the difference between these statements? I know that "var $test" declares a jquery variable, but what is the difference of a jquery variable with a general javascript variable ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Nothing. No difference. $ is a valid character in a JavaScript identifier but has no special meaning. In fact, in the ECMAScript 3 specification in section 7.6 it states that

> The dollar sign ($) and the underscore
>   (_) are permitted anywhere in an
>   identifier. The dollar sign is
>   intended for use only in mechanically
>   generated code.

... although events have now probably rendered that recommendation obsolete. Indeed, the recent ECMAScript 5 spec omits the final sentence.

Answer (score 30):

`$test` is a convention used to indicate that this variable is a jQuery object and you can call the standard functions on it while `test` could be a standard DOM element and you cannot call the `val` function on it for example.

For example:

```
var $test = $('#someId');
var test = document.getElementById('#someId');
```

You can do `$test.text();` but you cannot do `test.text();`

Comment: So that means even if I don't use the "$" sign, I will still be able to call the standard functions on that object, right?

Comment: @Sayem Ahmed: Right, it is just a name. It has absolutely **no** meaning! It would be same if you ask whether variable names starting with `t` are somehow special.

Comment: I never knew about this convention, but it does make a lot of sense! Thank you for this clarification, Felix.

Answer (score 2):

there is no difference between `var $test` and `var test`. but its always good to know what kind of data is in your variable: (for example if someone else just want to modify a function in your code without having to read, or have to console.log your vars to know whats in it)

here some examples:

```
var arrTest = [1, 2, a, b, c], //Array
objTest = {test: 1, test2: 2}, //Object
strTest = "test", //String
intTest = 4, //integer
$test = $("#test") //jqueryObject
```

but it would also work like this

```
var Test1 = [1, 2, a, b, c], //Array
test2 = {test: 1, test2: 2}, //Object
Test3 = "test", //String
Test4 = 4, //integer
$test = $("#test") //jquery Object
```

i think what confuses you is the `$()` form jquery.

Jquery is basically a function set on the variable name `$`:

```
var $ = function(e){ // the jquery magic }
```

but you can still use `$somethingelse` as variable.