# Why use $ (dollar sign) in the name of javascript variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why would a javascript variable start with a dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign)
>   [JQuery : What is the difference between “var test” and “var $test”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880926/jquery-what-is-the-difference-between-var-test-and-var-test)

What is the difference between this two ways of initializing variables?

```
var $val = 'something'

     OR

var val = 'something'
```

as I see they are the same thing.

Maybe in this case `$` is only the part of name in variable?
(it will become a meaningless question in that case:/)

Thanks

Comment: Yes, the last one (just being in a name that is, the rest I leave up to you :P )

Comment: So, did the question turned out to be meaningless? :)

Comment: @Reigel No:P i got much more then expect. Thanks much all of you

Answer (score 106, accepted):

**The `$` in the variable name is only part of the name**, but the **convention** is to use it to start variable names when the variable represents a jQuery object.

```
var $myHeaderDiv = $('#header');
var myHeaderDiv = document.getElementById('header');
```

Now later in your code, you know the `$myHeaderDiv` is already a jQuery object, so you can call jQuery functions:

```
$myHeaderDiv.fade();
```

#### To get from the DOM-variable to the jQuery variable:

```
var $myHeaderDiv = jQuery(myHeaderDiv); //assign to another variable
jQuery(myHeaderDiv).fade(); //use directly

//or, as the $ is aliased to the jQuery object if you don't specify otherwise:
var $myHeaderDiv = jQuery(myHeaderDiv); //assign
$(myHeaderDiv).fade(); //use
```

#### To get from the jQuery variable to the DOM-variable.

```
var myHeaderDiv = $myHeaderDiv.get(0);
```

Comment: Can you point to a reference that states that this is a jQuery convention?

Comment: Actually the convention is use it only in software generated code. jQuery and other libraries are misusing it.

Comment: It's a variant of hungarian notation really - instead of t_name to remind the programmer the name is still tainted, it uses $ to remind the programmer this is already a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks man. i'm using jQuery for a long time, but i've learned new important details from your answer. Thanks;)

Comment: A convention that I was not familiar with... +1

Comment: I think that even hungarians do not use that anymore :-). I tend to rely on searching rather than programmer consistency.

Comment: i think it isnt realy a convention but i think it would be nice if they make one of it

Comment: I've always used an array index to get from the jQuery variable to the DOM-variable: var myHeaderDiv = $myHeaderDiv[0]. Is there a better reason to use .get(0)?

Answer (score 12):

You are correct. $ is a part of the name of the variable.
This is not perl or PHP :)

Comment: Or QBASIC! (ahh, nostalgia)

Answer (score 5):

There are 28 letters in the alphabet as far as JavaScript is concerned. a-z, _ and $. Anywhere you can use a letter in JavaScript you can use $ as that letter. (*<c> Fellgall @ http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=186546*)

In your example $val and val will be two different variable names.

Comment: 27? `The dollar sign ($) and the underscore (_) are permitted anywhere in an IdentifierName.` As far as I can count - that's 28. Even your forum thread mentions that later on: `Oops, forgot that one - JavaScript has a 28 letter alphabet.`

Answer (score 5):

No real difference..

It is usally used to signify a variable holding a jquery or other javascript framework  object, because they can have shorthand `$` function..

It is just easier to identify the type of the contents..

Answer (score 3):

syom - in my case, i use the $ prefix to indicate that it's a variable that is referenced by jquery. It's purely a part of the variable and not a reserved character.

keeps it easy to identify in long code runs..

jim