# Why won't innerHTML work for me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This function uses jQuery to modify the contents of a DOM element. What am I doing wrong?

```
function updateScore() {
    alert("Test score is: " + bucket.score);
    $("#testScore").innerHTML = 'Current score is: + bucket.score';
}
```

The alert runs, but nothing else does. I have a `<p>` with the id `testScore`, but it doesn't change when I run the function. Why?

Thanks, Elliot Bonneville

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `.html()` on a jQuery object. `innerHTML` is for DOM-Elements.

```
$("#testScore").html('Current score is: '+ bucket.score);
```

If, for some reason, you **really** want to use `innerHTML`, you can [convert the jQuery Object back to its DOM variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360858/why-use-in-the-name-of-javascript-variables/3360883#3360883), for example using [0] or .get(0). Call like this, then:

```
$("#testScore")[0].innerHTML ='Current score is: '+ bucket.score
```

But I don't see why you would want to do that - since you're already writing in jQuery, there's no need to fallback to DOM methods that have a perfectly fine jQuery equivalent.

Comment: you can also get the html element itself with `[0]`. so `$("#testScore")[0].innerHTML = '...';

Comment: You'll need to put bucket.score out of the string (move the single quote `'` to the left) to have it evaluated.

Comment: The `[0]` part could be written as `$('#testScore').get(0)`, too.

Answer (score 2):

```
function updateScore() {
    alert("Test score is: " + bucket.score);
    $("#testScore").text('Current score is: ' + bucket.score);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#testScore").innerHTML('Current score is: + bucket.score');
```

The jQuery objects do not support assignment to the attributes. (Its a Javascript limitation) You have to call the function with a parameter to set something.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. You can see my page and view the source if you need to here: http://elliot.bonblogs.com/quiz/#quiz

Comment: It's not `innerHTML()`, it's `html()`.

Comment: A JavaScript limitation? This does not make sense to me.

Comment: @elusive, its a JavaScript limitation because they couldn't override the meaning of obj.innerHTML = X to do something special.

Comment: @Winston Ewert: I do not think that they did it like they did because of non-existing magic properties in JavaScript. `.html()` simply fits much better in the jQuery schema. It is chainable.