# jQuery caching elements, difference between $variable and variable?

Tags: jquery, caching, variables

I was wondering if someone could explain the difference in caching elements in JQuery. One with the dollar symbol and one without.

Here is an example:

```
var cached = $('.someElement'); 

var $cached = $('.someElement');
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is **no difference**. Both are cached, only the name of the variable is different.

Both `cached` and `$cached` are valid Javascript variables:

```
var $message = 'Hello';
var message = 'Hello';
```

The $variable syntax is just often used [to indicate the variable contains a jQuery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360858/why-use-in-the-name-of-javascript-variables/3360883#3360883), not another type (string, integer, DOM Element, ...). It's a kind of Hungarian notation, but it's just a convention amongst programmers. Nothing Javascript or jQuery imposes.

When people talk about caching a jQuery variable, they mean only **doing the lookup once**:

```
//Like this: cached: search is done once.
var clientSpan = $('#client');
clientSpan.hide();
clientSpan.show();
// ...

//Not like this: uncached
$('#client').hide();
$('#client').show();
// ...
```

Comment: Perfect. I will use that technique in the future.

Answer (score 4):

The `$` prefix is used to denote that the variable contains a jQuery object. In terms of code there is no difference, both elements in your example are now contained in a jQuery object, inside each variable.

For example:

```
var myVariable = $("#myElement").text(); // string
var $myVariable = $("#myElement"); // jQuery object
```