# JQuery - Reusing defined element

Tags: jquery, function, methods

I have an element that is repetitive. I tried to use it more than once but couldn't. I end up doing multiple times.

```
$(function(){
   $('#schstart1').datepicker({
      format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
      startDate: '01-01-1900'
    });  
    $('#schend1').datepicker({
      format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
      startDate: '01-01-1900'
    });  
    $('#schstart2').datepicker({
      format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
      startDate: '01-01-1900'
    });  
....
...
..
```

Is there anyway i can define #schstart only and reuse many times?

Comment: Use class instead. Add class needDatepicker to each element, then use `$(".needDatepicker").datepicker({...})`

Comment: Eh that works man! U should put in the answer section so i can tick it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use class instead. Add class needDatepicker to each element, then use

`$(".needDatepicker").datepicker({...})`

Answer (score 0):

This should work the same (just modify selector):

```
$('#schstart1, #schend1, #schstart2').datepicker({
  format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
  startDate: '01-01-1900'
});
```

Comment: Do i need to define the selectors?
Is there any way I can use #schstart only for more than 1 input field?

Answer (score 0):

Define it as a variable starting with `$`, call it whatever you like. It now represents a jQuery object and is saved as a variable so you can use it over and over without referencing it again to save memory.

```
var $schstart1 = $('#schstart1');

$schstart1.datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    startDate: '01-01-1900'
});
$schstart1.datepicker({
    format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
    startDate: '01-01-1900'
});
```

Check out this good answer [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3360883/1799136) if you'd like to learn more about jQuery object variables and how they work.